# In PhoneGap Webview, can server Response be intercepted and handled in native

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I found many answers to how a request from Phonegap Webview can be intercepted in Native and handled before being sent to the server.
I need to go the other way : I want to intercept the response from the server in Native before it is rendered in the Webview. Any possible way to do this?

Comment: can you give more details about what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: jcesarmobile : i want to see if i can do some sort of integrity checks on the data sent from the server ( using public key crypto) for some of the more sensitive pages. This is to handle man in the middle type scenarios where SSL has been compromised (many ways this could happen eg compromised CA cert or poodle type attacks) and i want to rely on application layer to check integrity.

Comment: search for information about doing that on the android webview, but as far as I know, the only ssl related method that provices the android webview (with the webViewClient) is for checking ssl erros, but nothing for just checking anytime